# How to find parenthesis bound strings in python

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and wanted to automate one of my assignments in a cybersecurity class.
I'm trying to figure out how I would look for the contents of a file that are bound by a set of parenthesis. The contents of the (.txt) file look like:

```
cow.jpg : jphide[v5](asdfl;kj88876)
fish.jpg : jphide[v5](65498ghjk;0-)
snake.jpg : jphide[v5](poi098*/8!@#)
test_practice_0707.jpg : jphide[v5](sJ*=tT@&Ve!2)
test_practice_0101.jpg : jphide[v5](nKFdFX+C!:V9)
test_practice_0808.jpg : jphide[v5](!~rFX3FXszx6)
test_practice_0202.jpg : jphide[v5](X&aC$|mg!wC2)
test_practice_0505.jpg : jphide[v5](pe8f%yC$V6Z3)
dog.jpg : negative`
```

And here is my code so far:

```
import sys, os, subprocess, glob, shutil

# Finding the .jpg files that will be copied.
sourcepath = os.getcwd() + '\\imgs\\'
destpath = 'stegdetect'
rawjpg = glob.glob(sourcepath + '*.jpg')

# Copying the said .jpg files into the destpath variable
for filename in rawjpg:
    shutil.copy(filename, destpath)

# Asks user for what password file they want to use.
passwords = raw_input("Enter your password file with the .txt extension:")
shutil.copy(passwords, 'stegdetect')

# Navigating to stegdetect. Feel like this could be abstracted.
os.chdir('stegdetect')

# Preparing the arguments then using subprocess to run
args = "stegbreak.exe -r rules.ini -f " + passwords + " -t p *.jpg"

# Uses open to open the output file, and then write the results to the file.
with open('cracks.txt', 'w') as f: # opens cracks.txt and prepares to w
        subprocess.call(args, stdout=f)

# Processing whats in the new file.
f = open('cracks.txt')
```

Comment: What kind of paranthesis? You can use regex, but you need to tell actual requirement to be able to help you.

Comment: What if the cracked password contains parenthesis?

Answer (score 2):

If it should just be bound by ( and ) you can use the following regex, which ensures starting ( and closing ) and you can have numbers and characters between them. You can add any other symbol also that you want to include.

`[\(][a-z A-Z 0-9]*[\)]`

```
[\(] - starts the bracket
[a-z A-Z 0-9]* - all text inside bracket
[\)] - closes the bracket
```

So for input `sdfsdfdsf(sdfdsfsdf)sdfsdfsdf` , the output will be `(sdfdsfsdf)`
Test this regex here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

> I'm learning Python

If you are learning you should consider alternative implementations, not only regexps.

TO iterate line by line of a text file you just open the file and for over the file handle:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something(line)
```

Each line is a string with the line contents, including the end-of-line char '/n'. To find the start index of a specific substring in a string you can use find:

```
>>> A = "hello (world)"
>>> A.find('(')
6
>>> A.find(')')
12
```

To get a substring from the string you can use the slice notation in the form:

```
>>> A[6:12]
'(world'
```

Comment: I'm sorry this is probably a dumb question, but what do you mean by considering alternative implementations? Like IronPython? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @ParkerPierce For every programming problem there are many solutions, implementations. You can solve your problem with a Regular Expression, but you can also solve it by writing code and doing string processing. Since you are just starting, it is in your best interest to explore diffrent kind of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions which are implemented in the [Python re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

a simple regex like `\(.*\)` could match your "parenthesis string"
but it would be better with a group `\((.*)\)` which allows to get only the content in the parenthesis.

```
import re

test_string = """cow.jpg : jphide[v5](asdfl;kj88876)
fish.jpg : jphide[v5](65498ghjk;0-)
snake.jpg : jphide[v5](poi098*/8!@#)
test_practice_0707.jpg : jphide[v5](sJ*=tT@&Ve!2)
test_practice_0101.jpg : jphide[v5](nKFdFX+C!:V9)
test_practice_0808.jpg : jphide[v5](!~rFX3FXszx6)
test_practice_0202.jpg : jphide[v5](X&aC$|mg!wC2)
test_practice_0505.jpg : jphide[v5](pe8f%yC$V6Z3)
dog.jpg : negative`"""

REGEX = re.compile(r'\((.*)\)', re.MULTILINE)

print(REGEX.findall(test_string))
# ['asdfl;kj88876', '65498ghjk;0-', 'poi098*/8!@#', 'sJ*=tT@&Ve!2', 'nKFdFX+C!:V9' , '!~rFX3FXszx6', 'X&aC$|mg!wC2', 'pe8f%yC$V6Z3']
```